# Configure Gnome by text files (Debian 10)

Tags: debian, gnome3, debian-buster

I am using Salt stack to keep all (15+) of my system configurations in sync.  I have recently switched to using Debian 10. It turns out that its Gnome has disabled the minimize and maximize buttons, so I need to make some modifications to its configuration.

Where does Debian store its Gnome configuration files?  Is this location relatively stable?  Can I count on it being in the "same place", so that I can automate putting the file there?

Or should I just configure Gnome programmatically, for example, by a shell command?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says:

> One dconf database consists of a single file in *binary* format, i.e. it
>   is not a text-file. The format is defined as gvdb (GVariant Database
>   file). It is a simple database file format that stores a mapping from
>   strings to GVariant values in a way that is extremely efficient for
>   lookups.
>
> The GNOME database file for each user is by default ~/.config/dconf/user, a file expected to be in GVDB format.

You can surely write a script that configures Gnome using dconf. See an example with window buttons [at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125765/how-do-i-add-minimize-maximize-buttons-to-gnome-shell-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Debian's GNOME configuration datastore is in ~/.config/dconf/user, but that file is a binary blob that can't really be directly manipulated.

As described in dconf(7), you can keep plain-text keyfiles in /etc/dconf/db/database.d/, which will be mixed into the dconf databases on a call to dconf update.  If you can find the relevant dconf settings, you can put a keyfile there that changes it.

---

As a side note, I am working on efficiently tracking all .config/ files in a GIT database, which involves converting an existing dconf database to and from a plain text format.  That's not needed to accomplish your goal, but I think it's worth mentioning that it might be relevant.